# Why does Python "&=" set operator act differently than "&=" integer operation?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does this set operation change set `s`?  It does not work the same way for the integer (bitwise) version of the same operator....

Set Operation `&=` (changes `s`):

```
s = set('abc')
t = set('bcd')
u=s
print u, s, t
u &= t
print u, s, t
```

results:

```
set(['a', 'c', 'b']) set(['a', 'c', 'b']) set(['c', 'b', 'd'])

set(['c', 'b']) set(['c', 'b']) set(['c', 'b', 'd'])
```

Bitwise operation `&=` (does not change `s`):

```
s = 7
t = 3
u=s
print u, s, t
u &= t
print u, s, t
```

Result:

```
7 7 3

3 7 3
```

Comment: Sets are mutable and integers aren't. Try it with a `frozenset`.

Comment: It works as expected with frozensets.  So, the operation isn't attempting to modify the set u (the same object as s at the beginning of the statement) in-place or it would have caused an exception.  What is it attempting to do?

Comment: Lists show the same behavior as sets for &=.  Tuples cause a TypeError.

Comment: Yes. Lists are also mutable. Tuples are not.

Comment: Frozensets are not mutable but don't cause a type error.  Where is the behavior of &= for mutable vs. immutable types documented?

Comment: If I use `&=` on two lists I get a TypeError.

Answer (score 5):

Integers implement the `&` operation but not the `&=` operation, so when you use `x &= y` it is expanded to `x = x & y` which simply reassigns the `x` variable rather than modifying its internal state (it wouldn't make much sense for `&` to mutate a value, just like it wouldn't make sense for `+`). Same for frozensets.

Sets implement the `&=` operation so it's not expanded to a variable reassignment but rather mutates the left hand side of the operator.

Tuples implement neither `&` nor `&=` so an error makes sense. However you get the same effect with `+=`: for tuples `+=` is expanded, for lists it's an in-place mutation because lists are mutable.

Any class can implement their own version of these operators. See [here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#numeric) for details. In particular `&` corresponds to `__and__` and `&=` to `__iand__`.

If you think about it, it's a sensible convention for mutable classes to implement the in-place operators to allow direct modification, but not immutable classes.

Comment: Thanks.  You gave me enough information to find "Augmented Assignment', PEP-203, and , my answer, in the Python 2.7.11 documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html.